# Keras model.fit crashes after random time "In[0] and In[1] has different ndims: [16,1] vs. [0]"

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tf.keras

When I fit my Keras network, sometimes the fit completes, and sometimes it errors. I have tried to make my implementation reproducible, and the fit produces the same losses at each epoch, but the code still crashes at a random time.

From the error message, it seems like I get a batch that is an array of one zero instead of the 16 items I expect.

I am using Tensorflow 2.7 and Python 3.8, in Docker on a Mac with Apple silicon, training on a CPU.

```
def train_model_for_records(tf):
    batch_size = 16
    past_date = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
    records = AnalysisRecord.objects.filter(sale_timestamp_1__gt=past_date.timestamp()).filter(baths__lt=10).filter(bedrooms__lt=10).filter(sale_price_2__gt=0).annotate(zip=Cast('sit_us_zip', IntegerField())).filter(sale_price_1__lt=1000001).filter(sale_price_1__gt=99999).values()

    Data = pd.DataFrame(list(records))
    for x in range(1, 5):
        Data[f'sale_year_{x}'] = Data[f'sale_timestamp_{x}'].apply(lambda sale_date:datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(sale_date).year)
        Data[f'list_year_{x}'] = Data[f'list_timestamp_{x}'].apply(lambda sale_date:datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(sale_date).year)
        Data[f'sale_month_{x}'] = Data[f'sale_timestamp_{x}'].apply(lambda sale_date:datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(sale_date).month)
        Data[f'list_month_{x}'] = Data[f'list_timestamp_{x}'].apply(lambda sale_date:datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(sale_date).month)

    # transform embeddings data
    value_count_map = {}
    value_map = {}

    for c in embedded_columns():
        c_map = {}
        for x in range(0, len(Data[c].unique())):
            key = Data[c].unique()[x]
            c_map[key] = x
        for index, row in Data.iterrows():
            row_value = row[c]
            Data.at[index,c] = c_map[row_value]
        value_count_map[c] = len(Data[c].unique()) 
        value_map[c] = c_map

    for c in all_columns():
        Data[c] = Data[c].astype(np.float32)
    Data["sale_price_1"] = Data["sale_price_1"].astype(np.float32)

    clean_dataset(Data)

    inputs = {}
    features = {}
    for ec in embedded_columns():
        inputs[ec] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None,), name=ec)
        features[ec] = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(value_count_map[ec], value_count_map[ec])(inputs[ec])
    for vc in value_columns():
        inputs[vc] = tf.keras.Input(shape=(None, 1), name=vc)
        features[vc] = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="relu")(inputs[vc])
    x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([features[key] for key in all_columns()])

    price_pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name="price")(x)

    model = tf.keras.Model(
        inputs=[inputs[key] for key in all_columns()],
        outputs=[price_pred],
    )
    model.compile(
        optimizer="adam",
        loss="mae",
    )
            
    analysis_data = {}
    for key in all_columns():
        analysis_data[key] = Data[key]
        
    model.fit(
        analysis_data,
        {"price": Data['sale_price_1']},
        epochs=10,
        batch_size=batch_size,
    )
    
    return model
    

def clean_dataset(df):
    assert isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame), "df needs to be a pd.DataFrame"
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    indices_to_keep = ~df.isin([np.nan, np.inf, -np.inf, 0]).any(1)



seed_value = 0
os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED']=str(seed_value)
random.seed(seed_value)
np.random.seed(seed_value)
tf.random.set_seed(seed_value)
# for later versions: 
tf.compat.v1.set_random_seed(seed_value)

# 5. Configure a new global `tensorflow` session
session_conf = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads=1, inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(sess)

model = train_model_for_records(tf)
```

Here is the output:

```
root@8e3b54c9c353:/code# python manage.py shell < real_estate/scripts/generate_neural_net.py 
Fetched 47555 records for properties.
Epoch 1/10
2972/2972 [==============================] - 13s 4ms/step - loss: 116922.3906
Epoch 2/10
2972/2972 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 94413.8125
Epoch 3/10
2972/2972 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 92659.2734
Epoch 4/10
2972/2972 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 90413.6250
Epoch 5/10
2972/2972 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 88272.1953
Epoch 6/10
2972/2972 [==============================] - 12s 4ms/step - loss: 85521.2734
Epoch 7/10
 142/2972 [>.............................] - ETA: 11s - loss: 85164.0312Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 93, in handle
    exec(sys.stdin.read(), globals())
  File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
  File "/code/real_estate/scripts/embedded_nn.py", line 140, in train_model_for_records
    model.fit(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 58, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  In[0] and In[1] has different ndims: [16,1] vs. [0]
     [[node model/dense_11/Tensordot/MatMul
 (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/core/dense.py:202)
]] [Op:__inference_train_function_7914]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node model/dense_11/Tensordot/MatMul:
In[0] model/dense_11/Tensordot/Reshape: 
In[1] model/dense_11/Tensordot/ReadVariableOp:

Operation defined at: (most recent call last)
>>>   File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
>>>     main()
>>> 
>>>   File "manage.py", line 18, in main
>>>     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
>>>     utility.execute()
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
>>>     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
>>>     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
>>>     output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 93, in handle
>>>     exec(sys.stdin.read(), globals())
>>> 
>>>   File "<string>", line 24, in <module>
>>> 
>>>   File "/code/real_estate/scripts/embedded_nn.py", line 140, in train_model_for_records
>>>     model.fit(
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
>>>     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1216, in fit
>>>     tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 878, in train_function
>>>     return step_function(self, iterator)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 867, in step_function
>>>     outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in run_step
>>>     outputs = model.train_step(data)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 808, in train_step
>>>     y_pred = self(x, training=True)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
>>>     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1083, in __call__
>>>     outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
>>>     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 451, in call
>>>     return self._run_internal_graph(
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/functional.py", line 589, in _run_internal_graph
>>>     outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
>>>     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1083, in __call__
>>>     outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 92, in error_handler
>>>     return fn(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/layers/core/dense.py", line 202, in call
>>>     outputs = tf.tensordot(inputs, self.kernel, [[rank - 1], [0]])
>>>
```

Comment: can you review the scenarios you have tested? like changing Keras version, testing on non-M1 testing outside docker/different docker image? Is your data public? if yes, please provide the link to.

Comment: Your example is not reproducible, I tried to fix it guessing some imports, but I don't know what to use for `AnalysisRecord`.